# Classification plot error

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, classification, svm

I am trying to plot a classification plot in R in which I am getting the error that formula not found. The code I tried:

```
# fit model
library(e1071)
svmfit <- svm(all~., data = sda, kernel = "radial", cost = 10, gamma = 1)
# plot results
plot(svmfit, sda)

> plot(svmfit, sda)# Error I am getting.
Error in plot.svm(svmfit, sda) : missing formula.
```

What I was expecting is something like given in this picture [image: Classification plot with one factor variable y and 2 other variables]
My data-set 'sda' contains five factors in first column('all') and rest there are 9 other numeric columns.
Can somebody suggest me how can i plot a classification graph.

My data format is

> sapply(sda, class)

```
>     all      Mean       Var      Skew       Kur       min       max 
 "factor" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" 
      IQR       med 
"numeric" "numeric"
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data `sda` has more than two dimensions, you must tell `plot` which two you want to see with a formula.  For example, if sda has variables x and y,  you could write

```
plot(svmfit, sda, y~x)
```

Of course, you need to replace x and y with actual variable names from your data. But if you specify only x and y values,  what will be used for the other variables?  You must also specify that using the `slice` argument.

There is a nice example of this on the help page `?plot.svm`

```
m2 <- svm(Species~., data = iris)
plot(m2, iris, Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length,
     slice = list(Sepal.Width = 3, Sepal.Length = 4))
```

[image: Iris plot]

Comment: I applied the same commands but got the error that  > "error in summery.factor(c(103L,102L,110L, 84L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 88L, 69L, :'min not meaningful for factors'. Please help.

Comment: Without your data, it is hard to diagnose. The _best_ solution is for you to type `dput(sda)` and paste the result into your question. If that is not practical,  it would be helpful for you to run `sapply(sda, class)` and paste the result into your question.

Comment: I have edit my question and inserted my data format.